# Difference between SqlConn and ODBC?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, odbc

I have a control which requires SQCN connection. So I supplied it with proper credentials and there's nothing wrong with it.

```
string connection = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=test;user ID=sa; Password=sa12345;";  
SqlConnection sqcn = new SqlConnection(connection);  
sqcn.Open();
```

Now due to requirements I need to change the dbConnection from SqlConnection to OdbcConnection. I used the same connection and replace Sql with Odbc but it shows an error

```
string connection = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=test;user ID=sa; Password=sa12345;";  
OdbcConnection odbc= new OdbcConnection(connection);  
odbc.Open();  

ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Can someone pls tell me if im missing something.. Tnx!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.connectionstring.aspx

Comment: oh I see pretty stupid of me. I thought the connection string is the same tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the proper driver for ODBC and define the data source. You can see data sources in **administrative tools -> ODBC Data Source**, also you can define data source here and reference it in your program via its **Name**.

[image]